# HIghcharts export server hosting ph-batik

Tags: php, highcharts, batik

[image]I had configured php-batik export server to save the charts in pdf format via svg
but in the pdf file charts title is not coming in the same format as in the svg file

I m using java 1.7 version

baitk version -1.7

Also issue is coming in the pdf conversion for IE8 and IE9 the captions are not coming correctly under the charts lots of text get trimmed

Answer (score 1):

This is sometimes the case, when specific fonts are not installed on the server, than it uses the default font on the server.

Comment: No problem with the Font only problem is that the captions are not coming more than two line while in chrome and FF it's fine see the attached scrren shot

Comment: In that case, you should provide also your Highcharts configuration with the options. Please setup an example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) which resembles your issue with the PHP export-server.